# Fetch incoming connections to a node within variable path neo4j

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Hi being a newbie to neo4j im stuck at the following query, any help would be really appreciated

```
Match (s1:state{name:”stop”}),(s2:state{name:”start”}),


Match p = ShortestPath((s1)-[*]—(s2)),


//How to fetch incoming connection to one of the node type(:condition) in variable path without querying entire graph


Match p2 = (e)-[*]—>(if:condition)
Return p,e
```

Also a followup question is once we have such subgraph how do we go about fetching nodes till (if:condition) within subgraph

Answer (score 0):

## How to retrieve nodes by label, with an inbound relationship in a path of any length?

Reworded from, "How to fetch incoming connection to one of the node type(:condition) in variable path without querying entire graph."

Directionality of relationships is the first and best thing to filter on, so start there (even if it is your end node).

But I think you should clarify your question a bit, as well as clean up your example.

```
MATCH (stop:state {name:"stop"}), (start:state {name:"start"})
MATCH (stop2:state:condition {name:"stop"})-[]->(stop)
MATCH p = ShortestPath((start)-[*]—(stop2))
RETURN p, stop2
```

As to how to do this without querying the entire graph... that entirely depends on your graph. More, when you make a query for *any* length path, it *must* query all paths from the starting node. If that node is connected to your entire graph, how can you expect to both "match all paths", and "not match all paths?"

#### Perhaps you meant, "Extract a node from a matched path?"

```
MATCH (stop:state {name:"stop"}), (start:state {name:"start"})
MATCH p = ShortestPath((start)-[*]—(stop2))
WITH p, nodes(p) AS n
WHERE ALL(node IN n WHERE node:condition)
RETURN p, n
```